# Performance issue when using .sheet modifier with Map embedded inside TabView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I want to display a sheet on top of a `Map` in SwiftUI. The following is a simplified example:

```
class ItemAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    private(set) var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            VStack {
                Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(MKCoordinateRegion(MKMapRect.world)), annotationItems: items()) { item in
                    MapMarker(coordinate: item.coord)
                }
                
                Button("Toggle Sheet") {
                    showSheet.toggle()
                }
                .padding()
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
                Text("some text")
            })
        }
    }
    
    private func items() -> [Item] {
        var res = [Item]()
        stride(from: -20, through: 20, by: 1).forEach { lat in
            stride(from: -50, through: 100, by: 5).forEach { long in
                res.append(Item(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)))
            }
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the above code produces a hang every time I open/close the Sheet.
[image: Map embedded inside TabView]

The hang doesn't occur, if I remove the `TabView` and display only the `VStack`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(MKCoordinateRegion(MKMapRect.world)), annotationItems: items()) { item in
                MapMarker(coordinate: item.coord)
            }
            
            Button("Toggle Sheet") {
                showSheet.toggle()
            }
            .padding()
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
            Text("some text")
        })
    }
    // ...
}
```

[image: Map without TabView]

If I replace the `TabView` with a `NavigationStack` the behaviour is the same.
In the real project I use a `MKMapView` as an `UIViewRepresentable` to be able to use clustering. But since the problem even occurs with `Map` I guess it's the same root cause. I suspect it's somehow related to the way a view is reloaded / redrawn if it's embedded inside a `TabView` / `NavigationStack`.
How can I avoid the hang while still using a `TabView` (that's mandatory for the real project)?